# image can not update in database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I write code for updating image it works when i upload new image. But when i dont upload image it caught exception as

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null

my query

```
   update student set photo = , updated_at = 2018-12-14 10:38:35.
```

my controller code

```
       function updatedata(Request $req)
   {

     dd($req->input());

     $post=User::find($req->input('userid'));
     $post->name=$req->input('name');
        $post->address=$req->input('address');
        $post->photo=$req->input('image');
        $post->gender=$req->input('gender');
        $post->hobbies= implode(',', Input::get('hobbies'));
        $post->std=$req->input('std');
        $requestData = $req->all();
       if($req->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image=$req->file('image');
        $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg'); // 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
        $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
        $pathToStore=public_path('/');

        if($validator->passes()) 
        {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
            $extension = $file -> getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture = sha1($filename . time()) . '.' . $extension;
            $upload_success = $file->move($pathToStore, $picture);

            if($upload_success)
            {
                //if success, create thumb
                $image = Image::make($picture)->resize(600, 531)->save($pathToStore,$picture);
                $oldfilename=$user->photo;
                $user->photo=$filename;
                Storage::delete($oldfilename);  
            }
        }
        $requestData['photo'] = "$pathToStore/{$picture}";     
      }
      $post->update($requestData);
      return redirect()->route('show');     
   }
```

Comment: you have to set your column photo nullable, or maybe you can check if request->file is false.. get the default value

Answer (score 1):

remove `$user->photo=$req->input('image');` outside of if condition and set null to true and default null in database image field.

```
    function updatedata(Request $req)
    {
        //dd($req->input());
        $user = User::find($req->input('userid'));
        if ($req->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $req->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(100, 100)->save($location);
            $oldfilename = $user->photo;
            Storage::delete($oldfilename);
            $input['photo'] = $filename;
         }
         else {
            $input['photo'] = $user->photo;
         }

        $input['name'] = $req->input('name');
        $input['address'] = $req->input('address');

        $updateUser = User::where('id', $req->input('userid'))->update($input);
        return redirect()->route('show');
    }
```

Comment: its not work. Your change remove exception but when i dont select image ,it will remove previous image path from database

Comment: dump `$input` with upload image and without upload image check it yor are getting correct result or not and update question with what you get.

Comment: If  i don't update image,then previous image name keep as it . It should not be null. In Your code it should be null

Comment: you need to add `photo` in `fillable`

Comment: i will check by dd($req->input()), result will be obtained but database path will not change

Comment: make sure `photo` is added in `$fillable` in user model.

Comment: thank u sir by making partial changes in  your code ,my task is complete

Comment: Edit answer so anyone got easily

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have add not null constraints in column 'photo'. So remove it and set default image path to it.

Answer (score 0):

set a default path of image if image not upload

```
if($req->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image=$req->file('image');
        $filename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location=public_path('/'.$filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(100,100)->save($location);
        $oldfilename=$user->photo;
        $user->photo=$filename;
        Storage::delete($oldfilename);
       }else {
         $user->photo = "set/to/default/path/image.jpg";
       }
```

otherwise update user table migration look like this and migrate again

```
$table->string('photo')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
function updatedata(Request $req)
   {
     //dd($req->input());
        $user=User::find($req->input('userid'));
        $user->name=$req->input('name');
        $user->address=$req->input('address');

        if($req->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image=$req->file('image');
        $filename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location=public_path('/'.$filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(100,100)->save($location);
        $oldfilename=$user->photo;
        $user->photo=$filename;
        Storage::delete($oldfilename);
        $user->photo=$req->input('image');
       }   else {
        $user->photo="notAvailable.jpg";
       } 
       $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('show');
   }
```